# Kustaanheimo-Stiefel (KS) transformation and initial conditions

Tags: coordinate-systems, regularization

I understand how Kustaanheimo-Stiefel (KS) transformations work and I have derived my equations of motion as well. However, I am struggling to find initial conditions in the KS space. How do I convert my position and velocity $(X,X')$ to the $(Q, Q')$ space? Here $$X = [x,y,z], X' = [vx,vy,vz], Q = [u1,u2,u3,u4], Q' = [u1', u2', u3', u4'],$$ with the $()' = d()/dtau$.